# To set a Blank date in a Apex formula

Tags: formula, date

I have a simple formula date field which I want to return a BLANK DATE (not a NULL) if the criteria is false. I tried many syntax, but all failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing called a blank date to my knowledge.

It would be either one of the below two

I) Any date

II) Null

You cannot assign any other value apart from these two!

Comment: Null returns Error? can you explain what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I created a temp blank date and pointed to that field in formula. Now all good now

Answer (score 3):

There is no blank date, rather you can get an empty field value.
You can use this to have an empty(no date value) field:

```
IF( 
 Condition, 
 NOW(), 
 NULL 
)
```